# How to access an Adapter object from a View in the ListView

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

I'm coming back to Android after a long while and I'm a bit stuck with some issue.
The app consists of a list of layouts, each of which is backed by a model through the adapter.
Each layout has several Views, one of them being a Spinner.
I want to modify the data in the Adapter when changing the value of the Spinner, but I don't know how to reference the object in the Adapter.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ArrayList<Troop> values = new ArrayList<Troop>();
    MySimpleArrayAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        values.add(new Troop());

        final ListView listView =(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

        adapter = new MySimpleArrayAdapter(
                this,
                values);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public class Troop {
        private String weapon;
        private int bs;
        private int total_modifier;

        public Troop() {

        }

        public int getBs() {
            return bs;
        }

        public void setBs(int bs) {
            this.bs = bs;
        }
    }

    public class MySimpleArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
        private final Context context;
        private ArrayList<Troop> troopers;
        private String[] possible_bs = new String[] {"10", "11", "12", "13", "15", "16"};

        public MySimpleArrayAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Troop> values) {
            super(context, -1, values);
            this.context = context;
            this.troopers = values;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, parent, false);

                Spinner bs_spinner = rowView.findViewById(R.id.bs_spinner);
                ArrayAdapter<String> bs_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                        context,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                        possible_bs);
                bs_spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new CustomOnItemSelectedListener());
                bs_spinner.setAdapter(bs_adapter);
            return rowView;
        }

    }

    public class CustomOnItemSelectedListener implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,long id) {
        // I want to call getBs on the Trooper correspoding to this view here
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You should `extends ArrayAdapter<Troop>`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The question is, how to access the adapter from the onItemSelected method?

Comment: It's a comment, not an answer ;) Which adapter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a lot going on here that I'd address. First, let's talk about your `ArrayAdapter` subclass.

As mentioned in a comment on your question, you should change it to `extends ArrayAdapter<Troop>`. This will cause `getItem()` to return `Troop` instead of `Object`.

There's no need for you to store your own `context` or `troopers` fields. The basic `ArrayAdapter` implementation stores a Context in the `mContext` field and you can access it via `getContext()`. Additionally, it stores the backing data in the `mObjects` field, and you can access it via `getItem()`.

Finally, if all items in your Adapter are going to share the same `possible_bs` value, you should make it a constant.

Next let's talk about the `AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener`.

You need a way to know which position (from your `MySimpleArrayAdapter`) your `Spinner` is living in (as opposed to the position of the item *inside* the `Spinner` the user has selected). I recommend passing this position in to a constructor and saving it as a private final field.

To get at the Adapter from inside the `Spinner`, you can access the `Adapter` backing the `AdapterView` argument by calling `parent.getAdapter()`, and then cast it to your desired type.

All together, you're left with this:

```
public static class MySimpleArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

    private static final String[] POSSIBLE_BS = new String[] {"10", "11", "12", "13", "15", "16"};

    public MySimpleArrayAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Troop> values) {
        super(context, -1, values);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, parent, false);

        Spinner bs_spinner = rowView.findViewById(R.id.bs_spinner);
        ArrayAdapter<String> bs_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(
                getContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                POSSIBLE_BS);
        bs_spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new CustomOnItemSelectedListener(position));
        bs_spinner.setAdapter(bs_adapter);
        return rowView;
    }

}

private static class CustomOnItemSelectedListener implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

    private final int troopPosition;

    private CustomOnItemSelectedListener(int troopPosition) {
        this.troopPosition = troopPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        MySimpleArrayAdapter adapter = (MySimpleArrayAdapter) parent.getAdapter();
        int bs = adapter.getItem(troopPosition).getBs();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't the position parameter be the position of the item selected on the spinner instead of the position of the element in the list view?

Comment: Yes, the `position` param to `onItemSelected()` is the position of the selected item in the `Spinner`. That is why you need to pass `troopPosition` to the `OnItemSelectedListener` and use that instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can move in the anonymous class.

You want to get both position elements if you want the current ListView element as well as the inner adapter position .

There's probably cleaner ways to do this, but it's the first idea I had

```
public class MySimpleArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Troop>  {
    private final Context context;
    private ArrayList<Troop> troopers;
    private String[] possible_bs = new String[] {"10", "11", "12", "13", "15", "16"};

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, parent, false);
            Spinner bs_spinner = rowView.findViewById(R.id.bs_spinner);

            final ArrayAdapter<String> bs_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                    context,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                    possible_bs);
            bs_spinner.setAdapter(bs_adapter);

            bs_spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() { 

                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
                    // You can access MySimpleArrayAdapter.this or bs_adapter
                    Troop t = troopers.get(position); // or getItem(position);
                    String bs = possible_bs[pos];
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                }

            });

        return rowView;
    }
```